# RandomAccessFile to read files in a Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am having problem to use `JWNL` wordnet in a Jar file.

`JWNL` uses RandomAccessFile to read wordnet dictionary files. In order to create a Jar file, wordnet dictionary files are put in resources/wordnet folder. As resources is in my Build Path, I have no problem to run the application I created in Eclipse. However, when I use another application to run the created jar file, I get the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/wordnet/data.noun (No such file or directory)

from the following code:

```
RandomAccess _file = new RandomAccessFile(path, _permissions);
```

I use the following code to check the current working directory:

```
URL location = PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
System.out.println(location.getFile());
```

It seems both situation have the same location: `/project/bin/`

How should I fix the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The key information you seem to be missing is that Jar files are compressed, and you can't "seek" because of the compression (which is I believe the [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm).

However, you could extract the file(s) into [temp file(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on start and then use that. Temp files would be removed on application exit, and are the best answer I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

> RandomAccessFile to read files in a Jar file

There are no files in a JAR file. There are JAR entries. You can't read them with `FileInputStreams,` `RandomAccessFiles,` or `FileReaders.`You need to use a [`JarInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) or its friends.